# Postgres - restore/maintain privileges after schema drop

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-grant

Long story short, a schema `schema1` in a postgres 12 db was dropped and a user `user1` uses the tables and `user1` is not the owner of the schema. Is there a way to maintain automatically the privileges that `user1` lost? this in order to avoid the manual restore of the privileges

Answer (score 0):

If the schema was dropped with CASCADE, then it wasn't just privileges that were lost, the actual data was as well.  Hope you have backups.

And if that is not what happened, then you need to explain what it is that did happen.

Comment: I'm learning about postgres 12 and getting to know if there's any differences with the 9.4 version which I'm actually used to. Aside from the data, I know the granularity of the privileges, I deleted the entire schema of my test database to test how it works and I did read this new feature default privileges, I was hoping for more info aside the doc https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html